# Unity: GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag isn't working and I don't know why

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a enemy AI script and a small part of the code isn't working. It's supposed to search for a game object with the Player tag when the target no longer exists. So, when the player collects a power up and a new player prefab spawns in its place it will search. However, it is not finding one and I don't know why.

Here is the part of the code that doesn't work:

```
    IEnumerator SearchForPlayer (){
    GameObject sResult = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("Player");
    if (sResult = null) {

                    yield return new WaitForSeconds (0.5f);
                    StartCoroutine (SearchForPlayer ());
            }
        else {
            target = sResult.transform;
            searchingForPlayer = false;
            StartCoroutine (UpdatePath());
            return false;
        }
            }
```

I know that my prefab has got the correct tag and that it is definitely getting to that part of the script. Does any one have any ideas why it's not working?

Comment: Becsuse you wrote `if(sResult = null)`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (sResult = null) {
```

Should be

```
 if (sResult == null) {
```

Single = is an assignment operator so you are setting the result to null instead of checking if it is null.

Comment: I can't believe I just made that mistake :S Thanks